# Updating data from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a better way to perform this code?

The file I am doing the update from could be a max of 10,000 rows - when I tested it for full 10,000 it works but takes ages to process.

I tested this without the lines that do the update and it flys through so it is definetly the update code that is the issu.

```
 'For each record in the Barcode table - lookup Master Supplier Key in Supplier file and update Amazon Match and Date last match checked fields
For l = 6 To LastRowLookup
    'look for the value in supplier key in Master Supplier file
            
    Application.StatusBar = "Processing Amazon Matches -  " & l - 5 & " of " & LastRowLookup - 5
             
    lkup = lookupSheet.Cells(l, 3)
    Brand = lookupSheet.Cells(l, 5)
    Category = lookupSheet.Cells(l, 6)
    Result = lookupSheet.Cells(l, 4)        
    '
    Set updaterow = Sheets("MASTER - Supplier File").Range("a1:r" & LastRowUpdate).Find(lkup)
    If Not updaterow Is Nothing Then
        updateSheet.Cells(updaterow.Row, 18).Value = DateUpd
        updateSheet.Cells(updaterow.Row, 17).Value = Result
        'updateSheet.Cells(updaterow.Row, 19).Value = Brand
        
    End If
Next l
```

Comment: sorry there is an END IF and Next L at the end of the code - it didnt paste...

Comment: The `Application.StatusBar` will slow it down. Add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` ar start and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at end.

Comment: I use the status bar to show a %complete - but will try then both to see what impact they have - thanks

Comment: I just spotted something - the find statement is going across the entire table - it just needs to check col a - made this change first and it has speeded up a bit - I should have the screen updating statements  - this is just part of the code - Sorry I should have made that clear - I will test the removing of the statusbar

Comment: just a thought - at the moment the statusbar update shows the record count compared to the total records being processed - so it is showing 1 of 10000, 2 of 10000.....  I want the progress to show so if I calculate what 25%, 50% and 75% of the total is and once record count hits those numbers i show 25% complete, 50% complete etc.... would that lessen the impact of using the Application Status bar?

Comment: *the entire table* - is it a table with a table name ? You can use `MOD` . `If l Mod 1000 = 0 Then Application.StatusBar = "etc`